# Swagger: How can I reference Document object in swagger file?

Tags: java, swagger

I am not able reference `org.w3c.dom.Document` in my swagger file. It's needed because one of the endpoint will be receiving xml document from third party service.
I have tried both:
`$ref: '#/definitions/org.w3c.dom.Document'` and `$ref: '#/definitions/Document'` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger is asking that you specify the schema of the object that you are going to receive.  Document isn't a schema--it's an implementation of a XML object representation, and from the swagger point of view, not terribly helpful when constructing an object to call your service with.  The more useful information would be the schema, or shape of the object you are sending.

You have two options:

1) Model the input object.  You can use `xml` hints to tell it if it's a wrapped array, etc.

2) Define it as type `object`.  That means, you don't have a concrete object definition.